# Get bullet movement direction?

Tags: mathematics

I have two objects, A and B, at two different points. I want B to fire at A. B's shot moves so far x and y every frame. How do I get the angle it needs to travel at as two numbers, one representing how much X changes and how much Y changes per frame?

Comment: This is basic vector math. Take a look [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/)

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need the angle. Just use:

```
x(v)= x(a)-x(b)

y(v)= y(a)-y(b)
```

Your new vector (x,y) (v) will have the ammount of movement in X and in Y axis needed to go from one point to another.

You can then calculate the ammount of distance per frame based on this vector.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to need the angle, only the delta vector between the two positions.

vA = vector representing position of A

vB = vector representing position of B

vD = vA - vB // distance and direction to travel

vD / len(vD) = vDu // direction of travel

And you multiply vDu with your speed per frame, this will give you the distance per frame.

Comment: Seems like we had the same idea at the same time :) xD

Comment: @Mayuso yup :) It could probably have fitted as a comment, but there was not much else to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you mentioned only mathematics tag so I'm assuming that you have to do everything manually, without built-in vectors functionality.

So, I'm writing here on of the may methods to do so.

First find the Slope between two points at which bullet A and B do exist, by which we can calculate angle through which I'll determine the direction.

Considerations:

Slope = **m**

A's position = **x1, y1**

B's position = **x2, y2**

tan inverse = **atan**

angle = **theta**

First find **m** between both bullets as,

**m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)**

**theta = atan(m)**

Now using parametric equation of circle which will give you the direction, and you want **B** to fire at **A**

**newX = Cos(theta)** --(1)

**newY = Sin(theta)**

**B's position = x2 + newX, y2 + newY**

**Repeat from (1)**